# Why we are interested in p>3 Schoof's algorithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, finite-fields, cryptography

In the Schoof's algorithm we are particularly interested in $char(K)>3$, where $K$ is the field. I know Schoof's algorithm is mostly used over large prime fields. Also, when we are transforming long Weierstrass equation in to short one, we need $char(K)>3$.

Can some one explain me the exact reason for considering $char(K)>3$?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it was mostly for convenience so the curve could be written in short Weierstrass form $y^2 = x^3 + Ax + B$.  These days one would not use Schoof's algorithm anyway in small characteristic (nor SEA etc.) because $p$-adic techniques are faster for fixed small $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir.  I am so happy that you replied to my question.

Comment: You're welcome.  FWIW the Wikipedia page for Schoof's algorithm gives a link to an implementation over finite fields of characteristic $2$; there's certainly no obstruction to doing it for $p=2$ or $p=3$, it's just that some of the details of the explicit formulas are different (and nowadays the $p$-adic algorithms compute the same thing more quickly).

Comment: @Noam D. Elkies: Can you give a reference for the $p$-adic techniques?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Seconding Timo Keller's request. I knew I wasn't up to speed, but I thought that SEA is more or less state of the art here :-)

Comment: Just filling in $p$-adic references: in characteristic 2 there is Mestre's AGM (see J.-F. Mestre, _Lettre à Gaudry et Harley_).  In small characteristic there is Satoh's canonical lifting algorithm and SST (see T. Satoh, _On $p$-adic point counting algorithms for elliptiic curves over finite fields_, ANTS V, Lecture Notes in Comput. Sci. 2369 (2002), pp. 43-66; and T. Satoh, B. Skjernaa, Y. Taguchi, _Fast cmoputation of canonical lifts of elliptic curves and its application to point counting_, Finite Fields Appl. 9 (2003) #1, pp. 89-101.  SEA is still state of the art in large characteristic.